# Page refreshing when attempting to save TextBox values

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a table with  TextBoxes and I set an UpdatePanel to the table and set a button that should save my new TextBoxes' value to the database as a trigger. But, when I press the button the page refreshes.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MaestroMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="ProjectDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            height: 68px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="Server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager"  runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>    
    <div class="cntr">
        <h1>
            פרטי הלקוח
        </h1>
    </div>
    <br />

   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="CustomerUpdatePanel">
   <ContentTemplate>

    <table id="CustomerDetailsTBL" class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoID" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" maxlength="9">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">ת.ז</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoAddress" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" maxlength="30">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">כתובת</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoFirstName" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server"
                        maxlength="15">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">שם פרטי</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoCity" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" maxlength="15">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">עיר</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoLastName" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" maxlength="15">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">שם משפחה</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoEmail" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">דוא"ל</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoPhone" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" maxlength="10">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">טלפון</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoFax" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" maxlength="10">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">פקס</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoMobile" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" maxlength="10">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">טלפון נייד</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoArchitectName" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server"
                        maxlength="15">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">שם האדריכל</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoArchitectMobile" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server"
                        maxlength="10">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">טלפון אדריכל</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoContractorName" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server"
                        maxlength="15">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">שם הקבלן</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoContractorPhone" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server"
                        maxlength="10">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">טלפון קבלן</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoSupervisorName" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server"
                        maxlength="15">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">שם המפקח</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="ProjectInfoSupervisorPhone" type="text" class="form-control" runat="server"
                        maxlength="10">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">טלפון מפקח</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ContentPlaceHolder3_SaveCustomerDetailsBTN" EventName="Click"/>
   </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any button inside the UpdatePanel to trigger a dynamic update of the UpdatePanel content only, and then the control id that make the trigger not exist `ContentPlaceHolder3_SaveCustomerDetailsBTN` in this code you give